# Why does allCases Variable of Protocol conforming to CaseIterable not conform to RandomAccessCollection?

Tags: swift, xcode, generics, swiftui, swift-protocols

**Context**

I have a protocol `Component` with an Object conforming to `Category` as its associated type. I also have a generic SwiftUI `ComponentsView`, in which I'd like to use the `Category` of the given `Component` inside a `ForEach`. However, I get the following Compiler Error:

> Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'C.C.AllCases' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'

---

**Code**

```swift
protocol Component {
    associatedtype C: Category
}

protocol Category: Identifiable, CaseIterable {
    var name: String { get }
}

struct ComponentsView<C: Component>: View {
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(C.C.allCases) { category in
            Text(category.name)
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Question**

- What causes the Compiler Error and how can I solve it?

*From my understanding, the `allCases` variable of `CaseIterable` returns an `Array`, which already conforms to `RandomAccessCollection`.*

Comment: But the compiler doesn’t know that, it sees the protocol CaseIterable and nothing else. The protocol has an associated type that conforms to Collection so the return type of allCases could be a lot of different types

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I don't get that. Every type conforming to Category must have an allCases Variable of type Array. Why does the compiler not know that?

Comment: See my edited comment above, the return type mustn’t be an Array, it could be a Set or Dictionary or something else. Read the documentation carefully and you will see this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `CaseIterable` [AllCases](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/caseiterable/allcases-swift.associatedtype) is defined with a default value:

```swift
associatedtype AllCases : Collection = [Self] where Self == Self.AllCases.Element
```

but that's all it is, a **default** value. In `ComponentsView`:

```swift
struct ComponentsView<C: Component>: View {
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(C.C.allCases) { category in
            Text(category.name)
        }
    }
}
```

All the compiler sees is a `Component`

```swift
protocol Component {
    associatedtype C: Category
}
```

that has a `Category` that *is* `CaseIterable`:

```swift
protocol Category: Identifiable, CaseIterable {
    var name: String { get }
}
```

But there is no information about its associated type. So, it could be an array, or it could be another type of collection.

Adding a constraint on `Component.C` solves the issue:

```swift
protocol Component {
    associatedtype C: Category where C.AllCases: RandomAccessCollection
}
```